# What is the shortcut to navigate to the next heading in Microsoft Word 2013?

Tags: microsoft-word, shortcuts, microsoft-word-2013, headers, navigation

In Word 2013, pressing <kbd>F6</kbd> sets focus on the local navigation menu but it does at the last heading that was selected on such menu instead of at the heading above the cursor (in which case a simple down arrow press would take me to the next heading). Therefore, I wonder if there is a shortcut that takes the cursor to the heading next to it (or above).

Answer (score 1):

I usually perform "go to" action by pressing (Ctrl + G) or (f5) then I select heading,
the shortcut for the next heading after doing so is (Ctrl + PageDwon), and the shortcut for the previous one is (Ctrl + PageUp).

Comment: Exactly what I asked but not what I wanted. What I was trying to ask for was a shortcut for, while being on the main work area, focus either current or next heading AT THE NAVIGATION MENU.